# Where is Vuetify render it's v-tooltip? I can't select or find it from Chrome element selector

Tags: javascript, css, vue.js, vuetify.js

The Official docs have v-tooltip live examples https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/tooltips/

In the very bottom, there is a **toggle version where I can keep tooltip alive**.

Now, although I kept the tooltip alive, **I can't select it using Chrome element selector**.

And, I can't even find the tooltip from the dev tool, I've searched all over the place, I just couldn't find where Vuetify rendered that tooltip.

I've searched for pseudo-elements as well.

Where is Vuetify render its tooltip?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's just on the same level as **div** with **v-application--wrap** class. That's why you can't select it using Chrome selector.

You can open developer tools by pressing **F12** and select it on **Elements** tab. As for your example, it's here:
[image: Chrome developer tab]

Sometimes you might need to debug your tooltips that hides on mouseover. In this case you can pause script evaluation by pressing **F8** on **Sources** tab.